# Javascript that allows use to pick a time and date that is translated into unixtime

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

Before I go though and build this maybe someone knows if it already exists.

I am looking for a script that allows someone to pick a time and date with a form (either inputs or selects) converts it into a unixtime and can convert a unixtime into this series of selects or inputs again.

I want this so someone that doesn't know code can input a date and then a Cron runs their desired task at approximately that time.

Google didn't produce any results so maybe one of you have seen something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap provides a [Date/Time Picker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) which supports year, month, day, hour and minute views.

They provide very useful examples, it should not be hard for you to fetch the picked value and convert it to your desired format.

Something like this should do:

```
var picked; // The picked value.
var unixTime = Date.parse(picked).getTime()/1000
```

using [DateJs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Simply attach an listener to the picker and use the converter on the picked value.

There are more [alternatives](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-date-time-picker/) but I'd probably go with this one.

Comment: I was writing the same post :p

Comment: You know I USE bootstrap and didn't even know it, Thanks!  5 minutes from now I'll accept the answer

Comment: I am having a lot of trouble with this.  I can't even copy and paste their example and get it to work.

Comment: The bootstrap example is not particularly good, it contains invalid markup and does not tell users what format it uses. It is also depdent on phantomjs and jquery.

Comment: He's using Bootstrap already so being dependent on jQuery hardly sounds like a issue. Good point about phantomjs, but like I said, there are other alternatives.

Comment: @Iscariot Non of the datetimepickers I linked in the alternatives working for you either? Anyway, what do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: I was looking at some of the alternatives as well.  I am going to go away from the bootstrap one.  We have taken so much out of the bootstrap we use because I find most of it to be for regular people or companies without web designers.  After about an hour on it, I figure I am going to go with http://www.jqueryrain.com/2013/11/datetimepicker-jquery-plugin-select-date-time/ but that may change with time.